How to get YouTube Video's Highlighted Comment in Google Sheet with REGEXEXTRACT or IMPORTXML
I want to get the author and text of a YT video's "highlighted comment" into a Google Sheet.
I did some research and found plenty of help for other metrics, but not this specific feature, and I'm still stuck.
The input is a comment-specific url, example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EytSWiKrFg&lc=Ugwy-pFoAiA7I02tBnF4AaABAg
The [example] outputs I'm looking for would be:
"aleattorium"
and
"- Why do you have this weird glass? - Ah, survival of the fittest"
In a Google Sheet I tried with IMPORTXML using what I think was the correct XPath like this:
=IMPORTXML($A1,"//*[@id=""content-text""]/span")
But I get the Error "Imported content is empty".
I've also experimented with REGEXEXTRACT, but I'm having trouble identifying the correct query. My process leads me to expect something similar to:
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA($A1)),"where Col1 contains 'content:""'", 0), """(.*)""")
Any solutions are much appreciated.

Based on my Stack Overflow answer 74936220 https://yt.lemnoslife.com/commentThreads?part=replies&id=Ugwy-pFoAiA7I02tBnF4AaABAg&videoId=0EytSWiKrFg returns what you are looking for.

Hey Harold! If you look at the source HTML of that page, I think you'll find the element your XPath is looking for is not there. I believe that the comments are loaded from a YouTube comments API into that page by JavaScript running in the page. NB Google Sheets' IMPORTXML function does not run JavaScript in the pages it scrapes, so it will not see those comments. You should probably call that same YouTube API, presumably the same one @BenjaminLoison suggests in his comment.
